# Creating Custom Tools in VS2017 with .NET Standard

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-generation, .net-standard

I've got a lot of code generation tools that use portable libraries.  Now that we're (apparently) dropping portable libraries for .NET Standard, I'm trying to convert my custom code generation tools to this stack.  Has anyone been able to do this?  I get the message that the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop package is incompatible with both .NET Standard and .Net Core.  How are we supposed to make custom tools for Visual Studio when the portable libraries are becoming obsolete and the new libraries aren't interoperable with Visual Studio (real question, not a rant)?

Comment: Custom tools for VS should target the full framework.  Reusable libraries should not be coupled to VS assemblies.

Comment: Does the codegen tool have to be coupled to VS? that locks consuming projects into VS and you can't work on them across platforms. Some other approaches using msbuild-integratesd code generation are also an option (e.g. https://github.com/AArnott/CodeGeneration.Roslyn)

Comment: @MartinUllrich - Yeah, they kinda do.  They're designed to create code when you change a schema, just like MSDataSetGenerator.

Comment: Then I don't think there is any reason to target a PCL or .NET Standard in the first place..

Comment: I have a lot of common libraries that are used in my code generation as well as other product my company builds.  I recently upgraded some of these common libraries from PCL to .NET Standard.  I was trying to come up with a common strategy to building shared libraries when I came across the VS tools.